# Как запустить программу из QTDesigner?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Вот, значит, решил опробовать PyQt4 и создал через `QtDesigner` графический интерфейс, перевел его в `.py` и вот что получилось! Как теперь это все мне запустить? Просто запустить без всего, просто чтобы его увидеть.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
_fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
_fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Programma(object):
def setupUi(self, Programma):
    Programma.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Programma"))
    Programma.resize(222, 59)
    Programma.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Programma", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(Programma)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Programma", "Поехали!", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Programma", "Закрыть!", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
    Programma.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(Programma)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    Programma.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(Programma)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Programma)

def retranslateUi(self, Programma):
    pass

class WidgetWithUiAsAttr(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_Programma()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Пусть даже у меня кнопки не будут ничего делать, чтобы понять, что оно из себя представляет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы мы читали книги, то:

Увидели бы это
[image]

а так же это
[image]

а еще вот это
[image]

Но я все же предпочитаю использовать конструкцию вида `uic.loadUi("file.ui",self)`.

Книги по теме: Boudewijn Rempt - GUI Programming with Python QT Edition [2001]. И А.Прохоренок - PyQt4. Создание оконных приложений на Python 3 (я пишу на python 2.7)